# Current data storage usage issue.

Tags: community, data-loader, salesforce-id, field-history

[image]

I have an old salesforce org that I have kept alive with one license remaining.
I have deleted all further data except Account , Contacts, Opportunity. After Deletion of the data I calculate **Current Data Storage Usage** and It's around **1.6 GB** and data usage show **2.6 GB**.

How can I find remaining data and delete that data?

Answer (score 1):

If you just did your delete, you would also need to empty your organization Recycle Bin. Otherwise, the storage is still in use.

Comment: I already clear my organization's recycle bin. But still Storage Data not reduce.

Comment: How recently did you do the delete? I believe the usage is calculated asynchronously, so it could take a while to update the totals. Also, just for thought, your 1.6GB is still over your orgs limit of 1GB.

Answer (score 0):

First, you may want to recognize that most of that data will be related to the Accounts and Opportunities that you've not deleted. Consequently, some of those records can't be deleted, such as the addresses related to contacts and accounts, products related to closed-won opportunities, etc.

With that having been said, you can go to the Developer Console and run queries for records on all of the objects you want to attempt to delete, then delete the lists that are returned. Expect some records to fail deletion. You may want to use the [Delete Results Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_deleteresult.htm#apex_methods_system_database_deleteresult) to determine which records were successfuly deleted.

Answer (score 0):

How much Chatter is there in your org?  The Storage Screen doesn't actually represent many 'system' records or the Chatter Feed/Post/Poll/etc records but they do take up room in your org.